# How to get user id with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I using the POST method for add `Item` to the database with Spring MVC. But each `Item` has field `userId`, it `FOREIGN KEY` to `users` table. Need to know user's id for this. I using Spring security for auth. May be there is a possibility get current user's id with `ServletContext` or `HttpSession`, may be spring security save user's id somewhere?

How to identify user which requested to the server with Spring MVC to data in the database?

```
@PostMapping("/get_all_items/add_item_page/add_item")
public String addItem(@RequestParam(value = "description")
                          final String description) {

    final Item item = new Item();

    item.setDescription(description);

    item.setAuthorId(/* ??? */);

    service.add(item);

    return "redirect:get_all_items";
}
```

Spring security implementation with using `UserDetails` so all details hidden from me, and I don't know how to intervene in auth process and intercept user's id in the authorysation stage.

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {...}

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {

    auth.userDetailsService(userService);
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with this approach

Make sure that you have your own `User` pojo class

```
  @Entity
  public class MyUser {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean isEnabled;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<MyAuthority> myAuthorities;
    ...
  }
```

Also an `Authority` pojo in order to define the user roles

```
@Entity
public class MyAuthority {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name; .....
```

Then the user repository, in this example I just declare a method to find by username and get an Optional to validate if the user exists.

```
public interface MyUserRepository extends CrudRepository<MyUser,Long> {
    public Optional<MyUser> findFirstByUsername(String username);
}
```

Create a user class that extends from `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` in order to wrap your custom user inside the definition of the spring security user.

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import java.util.Collection;
public class MySpringUser  extends User {

    private MyUser user;

    public MySpringUser(MyUser myUser, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(myUser.getUsername(), myUser.getPassword(), myUser.isEnabled()
                , true, true, true, authorities);
        this.setUser(myUser);   
    }

    public MyUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(MyUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And now the `UserDetailService` implementation, there is just one method to implement `loadUserByUsername` here is where the `MyUserRepository` is needed, in order to retrieve the user information from the repository by the username.

```
@Service
public class MyUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    MyUserRepository myUserRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Optional<MyUser> myUser = myUserRepository.findFirstByUsername(s);

        return myUser.map( (user) -> {
            return new MySpringUser(
                    user,
                    user.getMyAuthorities().stream().
                            map( authority ->
                                    new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName())).
                            collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found"));
    }
}
```

And now you can inject the `UserDetailService` because its implementation will be injected form `MyUserService` class.

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {

    auth.userDetailsService(userService);
}
```

then with this approach you can inject the `Principal` object to your controller, and inside the method you can cast the `Principal` object to `MySpringUser`, it is because `MySpringUser` is extended from `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` and User class implements the `UserDetails` interface.  Of course you can get all the rest of custom fields of the user because its definition is wrapped inside the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` class

```
@PostMapping("/get_all_items/add_item_page/add_item")
public String addItem(@RequestParam(value = "description")
                          final String description, Principal principal) {

    MySpringUser mySpringUser = (MySpringUser)principal;

    final Item item = new Item();

    item.setDescription(description);

    item.setAuthorId(mySpringUser.getUser().getId());

    service.add(item);

    return "redirect:get_all_items";
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I get ERROR when starting my App : `BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on ru.pravvich.domain.Item.author references an unknown entity: ru.pravvich.domain.SUser` . I have a JPA object User and SpringUser is wrapper which does not entity and hibernate fail build entityManagerFactory

Comment: ok please could you provide the SpringUser class i would like to know the user class that extends. could you provide the imports tha you are using on Spring  user.

Comment: also please the Item class

Comment: the error means that Item class has an autor field  of type SUser but SUser is not recognized as Entity by Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many things but the best thing is to create custer User class which extend org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

```
package com.walterwhites.library.model.pojo;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

import java.util.Collection;

@Getter
@Setter
public class MyUser extends User {

    long id;

    public MyUser(long id, String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

after you can use like below

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
 UserDetails client = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
long id =  ((MyUser) client).getId();
```

Cordially

Answer (score 0):

```
UserDetails client = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal(); 
long id = ((User) client).getUserId();    
System.out.println(id);
```

I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.doc.importexport.implementation.UserPrincipal cannot be cast to com.doc.importexport.model.User
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.
You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties